Generating binary arrays with alternating values based on change indices in NumPy
I have an array a of increasing indexes, e.g. [2 5 9 10], which indicates positions of value change. Assuming the output values are 0 and 1, I want to get array b:
[0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0]

Is there a NumPy magic to transform a into b?

One way among many others
a=np.array([2,5,9,10])
x=np.zeros((a.max()+1,), dtype=np.uint8)
x[a]=1
b=x.cumsum()%2

Some explanation (but I guess code, in this rare case, is its own explanation, since it is quite easy, once you see it)
x (after x[a]=1) contains 1 at each given position in a. So x.cumsum() contains a value that increments for each of those values: 0 for the 2 first, then 1  for 3 next then 2, then 3, then 4... So x.cumsum()%2 alternates between 1 and 0.
Note that I use np.uint8 type because I am cheap, and I can't help thinking "why shoud I pay 32 bits when 8 are enough for a size 11 array". But in reality, since 256 is even, it wouldn't really matter even if a had billions of values. Just x.cumsum() would roll back from 255 to 0 because of overflow. And then x.cumsum()%2 would have the same value.

x.cumsum()%2 very clever

elegant cumsum, cheers!

Your b ends up with uint64 for me, losing the cheapness you mention. Butb=np.bitwise_xor.accumulate(x) has uint8 (and doesn't need the modulo and the overflow talk).

That's funny: I was about to reply to some comments something like « I needed an iterative process — each value depends on the previous — so, cumsum was a natural choici, since there isn't any cumxor ». But yes, you're right: there is a cumxor, even if not by that name! And it is faster too (half of it because no need for a %2 and therefore of a second pass)

Yeah, was about 5x faster for the tiny array and about 9x faster for a large one in my testing. I think cumsum(dtype=np.uint8) was somewhere in between.

Btw x=np.zeros(a[-1]+1, ...) works, too. Oh and you actually temporarily take 128 bits per element, 64 in the cumsum array and 64 in the %2 array. With x=np.ones(10**6, dtype=np.uint8), your x.cumsum()%2 takes 16 MB whereas np.bitwise_xor.accumulate(x) only takes 1 MB (measured with tracemalloc.get_traced_memory()).

Probably you can try np.diff + np.repeat like below
d = np.diff([0] + a.tolist() + [max(a).tolist()+1])
np.repeat((np.arange(d.size)) % 2, d)

which gives
array([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0])


If S = [2 5 9 10] and res the final result, noticing that the value is 0 everywhere except inside the slices S[0]:S[1], S[2]:S[3], ... where it is 1:
res = np.zeros(max(S)+1)
idx = [slice(S[i], S[i+1] if i+1!=len(S) else len(res)) 
       for i in np.arange(len(S)) if not i%2]
res[np.r_[*idx]] = 1

[0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]


It produces incorrect result on [2,5,9,10,13,17,22] array.

@PaulJurczak you are right. I updated the formula. Thanks.

Place 1 at even positions and -1 at odd positions, fill the rest with 0, and compute the cumulative sum:
b = np.zeros(a[-1]+1, int)
b[a[0::2]] = 1
b[a[1::2]] = -1
b = b.cumsum()

